# Node/Expess Js how to get an ajax params from angular

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, node.js

I have a factory that sends an ajax userId call to my to node.

```
    usersModel.getUser = function(userId){

    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/details',
        params: { userId: userId}
    })

};
```

I get this console error from the client.

http://localhost:3000/users/details?userId=55ee772a797452cc77961fc4 404 (Not Found)

I have this route defined on my node.

```
    router.get('/users/details/:userId', function(req, res){

  console.log(req.params.userId);

  var userId = req.params.userId;



});
```

what am I doing wrong, how come my ajax call is not reaching my destination. 
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Different way of sending parameters. According to your node setup your url should look like `/users/details/55ee772a797452cc77961fc4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes don't match.  Angular $http `params` form query string, while express' `params` are URL path elements.

Change your angular request:

```
   return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/details/' + userId
    })
```